# WPF DataTrigger for ComboBox Item Change

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger, multidatatrigger

I'm designed a Contact Box in XAML

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" SelectedItem="{Binding Type, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="1">Mobile</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="2">Phone</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Contact, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The Properties are

```
public int Type { get; set; }
public string Contact { get; set; }
```

Initial Value of **`Type is ZERO`** (i.e., `Type = 0;`).

Conditions to Implement:

1. If Type is equal to 1 or 2, then I need to enable the TextBox - `IsEnabled = True`
2. If Type is 1, then the `TextBox.MaxLength` should be 10
3. If Type is 2, then the `TextBox.MaxLength` should be 11

I tried the following piece of Code:

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Value="0">
        <Setter Property="TextBox.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
    </DataTrigger>

    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Value="1">
        <Setter Property="TextBox.MaxLength" Value="10" />
    </DataTrigger>

    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Value="2">
        <Setter Property="TextBox.MaxLength" Value="11" />
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

But the above code is not working. Kindly assist me how to achieve the logic in `DataTrigger` within the `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TextBox could have a Style with DataTriggers:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Contact, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="10" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="11" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

If the `Type` property is suposed to change its value after the DataTemplate is instantiated, the owning class needs to implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.